# Unable to make multiple calls to separate post object fields with get_field() wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am having trouble making multiple calls to the Advanced Custom Fields get_field() method. I have successfully queried a custom post type, but then when I make queries to individual fields (they are post object fields) it correctly outputs the first query field, but none that follow.

Custom Post Query:

```
    function single_meal_plan_loop() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'ad_meal_plans',
        //'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'name' => 'meal-plan-test-1'
    );

$meal_plan_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $meal_plan_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while( $meal_plan_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $meal_plan_posts->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'accordianMealPlanList' );

        }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    }

}

single_meal_plan_loop();
```

Individual fields queries:

```
            $post_object = get_field('breakfast_day_1');

            if( $post_object ): 

                // override $post
                $post = $post_object;
                setup_postdata( $post ); 

                ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <!--field #2- no output to frontend-->
            <?php

            $post_object_2 = get_field('breakfast_day_2');

            if( $post_object_2 ): 

                // override $post
                $post = $post_object_2;
                setup_postdata( $post ); 


                ?>
```

Is there something I'm missing here? I've tried added a print_r() call inside of the custom post query per these docs and it does appear the post and it's data is all being retrieved correctly: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/. I've tried removing the call to wp_reset_postdata() after the first custom field because I thought I might be returning the query all the way back to the main post query that the custom post query is called from. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: why cant you echo directly get_field('breakfast_day_2');? instead of setup_postdata, there is no need to setup_postdata here

Comment: thanks for the response! well, I was following the docs on ACF which indicated I would need to call setup_postdata (since the field is a post object?). I tried adding the echo call just now with no success. ja

Comment: As I've been digging thru the ACF docs it seems like for post object fields the field first has to be retrieved and assigned to $post, unlike other fields that can be directly output with echo get_field(), as best I can tell

Comment: If there is a way to output this without calling setup_postdata that'd be preferable for sure, I just haven't been able to make that happen (sorry for multiple quick thread posts)